# Cipher functions:OPENSSL_internal:BAD_DECRYPT

Tags: node.js, cryptography

If you're trying to decrypt a string using nodejs, you will get this error if you're not using the proper input encoding and output encoding.

When doing decrypt, the input / output should be reverse of what was used during input.

```
 var mykey = _crypt.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);
        var myNom = mykey.update(nom, 'utf8', 'hex')
        myNom += mykey.final('hex');
        console.log("myNom: ", myNom.toString())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decrypt phase is the opposite input / output encoding.

```
 var mykey = _crypt.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);
        var myNom = mykey.update(cipheredtextgoeshere, 'hex', 'utf8') //reversed
        myNom += mykey.final('utf8'); //reversed
        console.log("Decrypted: ", myNom.toString())
```